# Is there any caching framework available for .NET?

Tags: .net, caching, ncache

I've searched and researched whole stackexchange stuffs but couldn't find anything properly that could help me in my situation. Summary goes like this, I want to implement a caching store mechanism in C# which will help me in accessing the data faster but catch is that I need that data to be properly synced with database. For example: My applications has various modules which governs various areas for the client to access. **I want an framework which at the time of login gets all the required module information for the user and maintains the cache (I can do that through code) during the lifetime of the user if there is any change/updation in the module information in the DB that should reflect in the cache dynamically**

I tried to look for:
1. Redis : But it is not solving the problem as far as I've searched it handle the static data.
2. I can use SQLCacheDependency class but don't know the use case I am looking for handles this or not.

Meanwhile I am looking for NCache for .NET.

Any ideas on how to tackle this or is there any framework that I can use with .NET?

Thanks

Comment: Look for SQLNotification

Comment: Read through [this MSDN section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/t9x04ed2(v=vs.110).aspx) and see if Query Notifications would apply for what you want.

Comment: @surajsharma Does my answer help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're heading in the right direction.
Use NCache Open Source for caching needs.

For DB synchronization use SQL Notification and invalidate items in the cache yourself.

SQL Synchronization is by default [fully supported](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/edition-comparison.html) in NCache Enterprise but you would have to buy it then.

http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/database-synchronization.html